# Bitcoin transactions with multiple participants from input side

Tags: transactions, coinjoin

Is there any other type of bitcoin transactions with multiple partisipants from the input side except different types of CoinJoin transactions?

Answer (score 2):

Multisig inputs typically have multiple participants. Usually multiple parties are required to sign the transaction.